# Reference to the segue source view controller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, segue, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Within my `viewDidLoad` I would like some custom code based upon the previous controller.

How can I access the segue source controller or the previous segue identifier in the destination controller's viewDidLoad to handle this?

Comment: Do you mean in the destination controller? You're last sentence is not clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to get a reference to the segue that created you. You could create a property (sourceVC in my example) in the destination controller, and assign self to this property in the prepareForSegue method (in the source view controller):

```
[(DestinationVCClass *)segue.destinationViewController sourceVC] = self;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `[self presentingViewController]` and you'll be able to access the VC that issued the segue. I usually like to couple it with `isMemberOfClass:` for a situation like this.

Comment: This will only work if the segue is modal, it won't work for a push.

Comment: It sounds like he's talking about a modal segue, but yeah good call.

Comment: I get my rootViewController by calling this method, so it seems the logic is a bit broken.

Answer (score 0):

You do the following in the unwinding segue method in the destination

```
self.source = (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue.sourceViewController;
```

Define source as a UIStoryboardSegue in the destination. The above line will give the source or the previous segue.