# Application screen sequence in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift3, swift3.2

In the application I can go from screen A to B to C.
Also I can go from screen A to E and also I can go from screen C to E.

I want to know the entry point from where Controller E is presented.

PS : application is storyboard less and can’t post code due to confidentiality.

App is in Swift 3.
Looking for some suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by the entry point?

Comment: I mean by entry point that if controller E is launched by controller A or C. So entry point for Controller E is A or C.

Comment: @Shruti : You want top root view controller which is loaded from UIWindow? or you want last view controller which is presented current viewcontroller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference to the segue source view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846760/reference-to-the-segue-source-view-controller)

Comment: @AnkitChauhan I want the last view from where this current view controller is presented

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just use the parent property of E viewController and check the source that presented it you can do something like

```
           if let parentController = self.parent as? A {
           //do smething
           }
           else if let parentController = self.parent as? C {
           //do smething
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to pass some data in your segue

i.e.

```
if segue.identifier == "showDest"{
let destVc = segue.destination as! YourViewController
destVC.source = currentVC
}
```